# How do I write a Django query with a subquery as part of the WHERE clause?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, subquery

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a Django query where there's a subquery as part of a where clause.  Here's the models ...

```python
class Article(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleManager()
    title = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    elapsed_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    votes = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)


class StatByHour(models.Model):
    index = models.FloatField(default=0)
    # this tracks the hour when the article came out
    hour_of_day = IntegerField(
        null=False,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(23),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ]
    )
```

In PostGres, the query would look similar to

```sql
SELECT *
FROM article a,
     articlestat ast
WHERE a.id = ast.article_id
  AND ast.votes > 100 * (
    SELECT "index" 
    FROM statbyhour 
    WHERE hour_of_day = extract(hour from (a.created_on + 1000 * interval '1 second')))
```

Notice the subquery as part of the WHERE clause

```sql
ast.votes > 100 * (select index from statbyhour where hour_of_day = extract(hour from (a.created_on + 1000 * interval '1 second')))
```

So I thought I could do something like this ...

```
hour_filter = Func(
    Func(
        (F("article__created_on") + avg_fp_time_in_seconds * "interval '1 second'"),
        function='HOUR FROM'),
    function='EXTRACT')
...
votes_criterion2 = Q(votes__gte=F("article__website__stats__total_score") / F(
    "article__website__stats__num_articles") * settings.TRENDING_PCT_FLOOR *
                                StatByHour.objects.get(hour_of_day=hour_filter) * day_of_week_index)
qset = ArticleStat.objects.filter(votes_criterion1 & votes_criterion2,
                                  comments__lte=25)
```

but this results in a "Cannot resolve keyword 'article' into field. Choices are: hour_of_day, id, index, num_articles, total_score" error.  I think this is because Django is evaulating my "StatByHour.objects" query before the larger query within it is run, but I don't know how to rewrite things to get the subquery to run at the same time.

**Edit:** K, moved my subquery into an actual "Subquery" function and referenced the filter I created using OuterRef ...

```
hour_filter = Func(
    Func(
        (F("article__created_on") + avg_fp_time_in_seconds * "interval '1 second'"),
        function='HOUR FROM'),
    function='EXTRACT')
query = StatByHour.objects.get(hour_of_day=OuterRef(hour_filter))


...
votes_criterion2 = Q(votes__gte=F("article__website__stats__total_score") / F(
    "article__website__stats__num_articles") * settings.TRENDING_PCT_FLOOR *
                                Subquery(query) * 
                 day_of_week_index)
qset = ArticleStat.objects.filter(votes_criterion1 & votes_criterion2,
                                  comments__lte=25)
```

and this results in an

```
This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

which is odd because I am using it in a subquery.

**Edit #2:** Even after changing the query per the answer given ...

```
hour_filter = Func(
    Func(
        (F("article__created_on") + avg_fp_time_in_seconds * "interval '1 second'"),
        function='HOUR FROM'),
    function='EXTRACT')
query = StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=OuterRef(hour_filter))[:1]

...
votes_criterion2 = Q(votes__gte=F("article__website__stats__total_score") / F(
    "article__website__stats__num_articles") * settings.TRENDING_PCT_FLOOR *
                                Subquery(query) *
                                day_of_week_index)
qset = ArticleStat.objects.filter(et_criterion1 & et_criterion2 & et_criterion3,
                                  votes_criterion1 & votes_criterion2,
                                  article__front_page_first_appeared_date__isnull=True,
                                  comments__lte=25)
```

I still get the error

```
'Func' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: Look into [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). Subqueries with an [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) resolve references to the outer query at execution time, which solves your problem. Update the question with your attempt if it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my quesiton with the update.  So I put things in a Subquery with what I thought was the proper OuterRef, but got the confusing error, "This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.".

Answer (score 5):

[Subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) need to be queries that are not immediately evaluated so that their evaluation can be postponed until the outer query is run. `get()` does not fit the bill as it is executed immediately and returns an object instance rather than a `Queryset`.

However, substituting `filter` for `get` and then taking a `[:1]` slice should work:

```
StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=OuterRef('hour_filter')).values('hour_of_day')[:1]
```

Note how the field reference in [OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.OuterRef) is a string literal rather than a variable.

Moreover, subqueries need to return a single column and a single row (as they are assigned to a single field), hence the `values()` and the slicing above.

Also, I haven't used a subquery in a `Q` object yet; I'm not sure it will work. You may have to save the subquery output in an annotation first and then use that for your filter calculations.

Comment: I think you meant to have hour_filter without the single quotes to mirror the filter var I created (With single quotes the error "Cannot resolve keyword 'hour_filter' into field. Choices are: article, article_id, elapsed_time_in_seconds, id, votes" appears).  But even without single quotes I get the error, "'Func' object has no attribute 'split'" even though I don't have the word "split" anywhere in my filter.

Comment: `'hour_filter'` refers back to an (annotated) field in the outer query (that you are required to make). `OuterRef` needs a field name, not a `Func` expression. The error you mention is a syntax error, e.g. a closing bracket in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Use filtering by a subquery that itself is filtered with `hour_of_day=ExtractHour(OuterRef('article__created_on') + timedelta(seconds=avg_fp_time_in_seconds))`. Real code will require one extra `ExpressionWrapper` and only works on `Django >= 2.1.0`:

```python
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Subquery, Value
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractHour, Coalesce
from django.db.models.expressions import ExpressionWrapper


relevant_hour_stats = (
    StatByHour.objects
    .filter(
        hour_of_day=ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(
            OuterRef('article__created_on')  # NOTE: `OuterRef()+Expression` works only on Django >= 2.1.0
            +
            datetime.timedelta(seconds=avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
            output_field=models.DateTimeField()
        )),
    )
    .annotate(
        votes_threshold=Coalesce(
            100.0 * F('index'),
            0.0,
            output_field=models.FloatField(),
        ),
    )
    .order_by('-votes_threshold')
    # NOTE: your StatByHour model does not have unique=True on hour_of_day
    # field, so there may be several stat for same hour.
    # And from your SQL example it's unclear how should they be handled. So I
    # assume that "greatest" threshold is needed.
)

article_stats = (
    ArticleStat.objects
    .all()
    .filter(
        votes__gt=Coalesce(
            Subquery(relevant_hour_stats.values('votes_threshold')[:1]),
            Value(0.0),
            output_field=models.FloatField(),
        ),
    )
)
```

P.S. It would be much easier if you set up some "demo project" on github so that anyone can clone it and check their ideas locally.

P.P.S. This code is tested to be working, but on different models/fields:

```python
In [15]: relevant_something = (ModelOne.objects.filter(index=ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(OuterRef('due_date') + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1000), output_field=models.DateTimeField()))).annotate(votes_threshold=100*F('indent')).order_by('-votes_threshold'))

In [16]: ts = ModelTwo.objects.all().filter(votes__gt=Subquery(relevant_notes.values('votes_threshold')[:1], output_field=models.IntegerField()))

In [17]: print(ts.query)
```

```sql
SELECT 
    ...
FROM 
    "some_app_model_two" 
WHERE 
    "some_app_model_two"."votes" > (
        SELECT 
            (100 * U0."indent") AS "votes_threshold" 
        FROM 
            "some_app_model_one" U0 
        WHERE 
            U0."index" = (
                EXTRACT(
                    'hour' 
                    FROM ("some_app_model_two"."due_date" + 0:16:40) 
                    AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'
                )
            ) 
        ORDER BY "votes_threshold" DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    )
ORDER BY 
    "some_app_model_two"."due_date" ASC, 
    "some_app_model_two"."priority" ASC, 
    "some_app_model_two"."updated_at" DESC
```

So if you are getting any errors with it, then please show ACTUAL code that you are running

Comment: Thanks -- one quesiton.  You are using ExtractHour("created_on"), which is close to what I'm doing but not exactly.  I want to extract the hour from the expression, 'F("article__created_on") + avg_fp_time_in_seconds * "interval '1 second'"' where "avg_fp_time_in_seconds" is just some number, we can call it 1000 for simplicity.  How do I incorporate all that other stuff into the ExtractHour function?

Comment: django expressions can understand timedelta objects... So it can understand this: `ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(F('article__created_on') + datetime.timedelta(seconds=avg_fp_time_in_seconds)))`. Updated my answer

Comment: @Dave, I have an idea why your attempts failed with `object has no attribute 'split'`: `OuterRef` supports field-names only (not expressions like `Func(...)`). Other issues with your sample code: `1000* "interval '1 second'"` will result in a string repeated 1000 times. And also strings are considered to be field-names and will be converted to "table_name.VALUE". Even if You use `Value("interval '1second'")` it will be escaped in SQL as a string. So correct way would be to directly use `datetime.timedelta` as shown in my answer

Comment: Ok, making some progress.  I now get a "Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field." error on the "votes_above_threshold__gt=0," line.  "votes" is a FloatField so I can't figure out what it's complaining about.

Comment: use `ExpressionWrapper(..., output_field=models.SomeField())` around any "operand-joined"  values. E.g.: `foo=ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(x+y+z, output_field=models.DateTimeField()))`, `bar=ExpressionWrapper(F('votes')-Subquery(y), output_field=models.FloatField())`. NOTE: you can use `Coalesce` for the same effect

Comment: I'm trying both "ExpressionWrapper" and "Coalesce" and getting an error "Coalesce must take at least two expressions".  I'm not sure if this is related to anything you have provided or my own silliness so I opened another question about it here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978773/coalesce-must-take-at-least-two-expressions .

Comment: `Coalesce` requires another argument, that will be used in the case when first argument resolves to `NULL` in the DB (just like `COALESCE` in SQL). So: `Coalesce(F('votes') - Subquery(...), 0.0, output_field=models.FloatField())`: `F('votes') - Subquery(...)` -- first expression, `0.0` -- second, `output_field=...` -- not an ["Expression"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/)

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  So now the query runs but it times out.  When I look at the resulting SQL, the subquery is not included as part of the WHERE clause, but rather as something queried in the FROM.  Very odd.  I will have to stare at thie more.

Comment: @Dave There might be a performance problem because "extractHour" is used both as a filtering condition and in "annotated" fields. Final query might be simplified by using `.values_list('article_id', 'elapsed_time_in_seconds', 'votes', named=True)` (include any needed fields except `shifter_article_create_hour` and `votes_above_threshold`) at the end of the query. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I put the "values_list" exactly as you have it here "ArticleStat.objects.all().values_list(..."
but still the resulting SQL includes "SELECT "articlestat.votes", ... EXTRACT('hour' FROM ("article"."created_on" + 4:07 ... FROM articlestat INNER JOIN ...".  Is there possibly a simpler way just to get my generated SQL to include the subquery in the WHERE clause, e.g. "ast.votes > 100 * (subquery) ..."?

Comment: @Dave changed answer so that it does not use annotations in "main query", and so resulting SQL is a lot simpler even without use of `.values(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to move as much as possible into annotations to clarify what's going on.

You can use the [`Extract`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) function to get the hour. If you want to incorporate the more complex `avg_fp_time_in_seconds` stuff, you'll need to define your own `Func`, which I haven't tried to duplicate as it would deserve its own post (this might be where the `'Func' object has no attribute 'split'` error was coming from).

```
# First, add a field for the hour 
articles_with_hour = Article.objects.annotate(created_on_hour=ExtractHour('created_on'))

# Set up the subquery, referencing the annotated field
for_this_hour = StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=OuterRef('created_on_hour'))

# Add the subquery, making sure to slice down to one value
articles_with_hour_index = articles_with_hour.annotate(
    index_for_this_hour=Subquery(for_this_hour.values('index')[:1]),
)

# Add the website averages for later calculations 
#  (note if total_score and num_articles are different field types
#  you may need an ExpressionWrapper)
articles_with_avg_website_score = articles_with_hour_index.annotate(
    average_article_score_for_website=(
        F("website__stats__total_score") / F("website__stats__num_articles")
    )
)

# Use the averages to calculate the trending floor for each article
articles_with_trending_floor = articles_with_avg_website_score.annotate(
    trending_floor=F('average_article_score_for_website') * settings.TRENDING_PCT_FLOOR,
)

# Set up the criteria, referencing fields that are already annotated on the qs
# ...
votes_gte_trending_floor_for_this_hour_criterion = Q(articlestats__votes__gte=(
    F('trending_floor')
    * F('index_for_this_hour')
    * day_of_week_index  # not sure where this comes from?
))
# ...

# Then just filter down (note this is an Article QuerySet, not ArticleStat)
qset = articles_with_trending_floor.filter(
    votes_gte_trending_floor_for_this_hour_criterion,
    # other criteria
    front_page_first_appeared_date__isnull=True,
    articlestats__comments__lte=25,
)
```

Many of these calculations could be condensed, and it may even be possible to do everything in a single `annotate` call using multiple kwargs, but I think laying it all out makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks for this although I can't figure out from your answer where you write the equivalent to the "Subquery(query) " clause that seems to be causing me so many problems.

Comment: The subquery is included in an annotation `index_for_this_hour=Subquery(for_this_hour.values('index')[:1])`, which gives you a new field "index_for_this_hour" to use like a normal field from then on (within `votes_gte_trending_floor_for_this_hour_criterion`). All the subquery examples at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions use this construct; I'm not sure if using it like an `F` object within a `Q` object is supported (as Endre Both suggested).

Answer (score 0):

It sure seems like a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) solution.

Django >= 1.11

> As a warning, I did test the code, but just with the models, I didn't have any data, so, this answer it is just an effort for pointing you out in the right direction

```
# Query that references an outer field from another model, in this case created_on.
# On wich we are performing a lookup in order to "extract" the hour (assuming here)
# a DateTimeField or a TimeField.
stat_by_hour = StatByHour.objects.filter(hour_of_day=OuterRef('created_on__hour'))


# Then filter articles, that have articlestats.votes 
# greater than 100 * stat_by_hour.index
result = Article.objects.filter(
    articlestats__votes__gt=100 * Subquery(stat_by_hour.values('index')[:1], output_field=FloatField())
)
```

At first glance, it looks you could need to perform an `order_by('index')` or `order_by('-index')` in your subquery, that way the slice `[:1]` will get the minimum or the maximum (depending on your needs.)

I'm sure you can use this (or something very very similar) to achieve what you want.

Comment: I keep getting the same error -- "'Func' object has no attribute 'split'" on that line "articlestats__votes__gt=100 * Subquery(stat_by_hour.values('index')[:1], output_field=FloatField())" .  Wish Django was a little clearer about what it wants there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Django queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/). I think you could solve the problem by changing the SQL base queries to what Django offers.

If it doesn't work, you are able to [perform raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/).