# Coalesce must take at least two expressions

Tags: django, python-3.x, model, coalesce

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I want to write a Coalesce expression to help me write a larger Django query.  I have

```
            Coalesce(
                F("votes")
                -
                Subquery(relevant_hour_stats.values('votes_threshold')[:1]),
                output_field=models.FloatField())
```

Here is the expression in context ...

```
qset = (
    ArticleStat.objects
        .all()
        .annotate(
        shifted_article_create_hour=ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(
            F('article__created_on')
            +
            timedelta(seconds=avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
            output_field=models.DateTimeField()
        ))
    )
        .annotate(
        votes_above_threshold=(
                Coalesce(
                    F("votes")
                    -
                    Subquery(relevant_hour_stats.values('votes_threshold')[:1]),
                    output_field=models.FloatField())
        ),
    )
        .filter(
        votes_above_threshold__gt=0,
    )
)
```

but this is resulting in a

```
Coalesce must take at least two expressions
```

complaining about the line

```
output_field=models.FloatField()
```

as far as I can tell, I have two expressions.  What else could the error be referring to?

Comment: What are the two expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Expression" in the terms of django are instances of `django.db.models.expressions.Expression`.

`F('votes')` — expression.

`Subquery(...)` — expression too.

But `expression+expression == combined_expression` so `F(...) - Subquery(...)` is a single "complex" expression.

What you need is a second **POSITIONAL** argument for Coalesce:

```py
Coalesce(
    (F(...) - Subquery(relevant_hour_stats.values('votes_threshold')[:1])),  # First expression
    Value(0.0),  # Second expression
    output_field=models.FloatField()
)
```

And I think that subquery can potentially result in NULL (not `F()`), so it's better to wrap only Subquery in the Coalesce:

```py
qset = (
    ArticleStat.objects
        .all()
        .annotate(
            shifted_article_create_hour=ExtractHour(
                ExpressionWrapper(
                    F('article__created_on') + timedelta(seconds=avg_fp_time_in_seconds),
                    output_field=models.DateTimeField()
                )
            ),
        )
        .annotate(
            votes_above_threshold=(  
                # Single expression F()-Coalesce(...) wrapped in parenthesis
                F("votes") - Coalesce(
                    # 2 expressions as arguments to Coalesce:
                    Subquery(relevant_hour_stats.values('votes_threshold')[:1]),
                    Value(0.0),
                    output_field=models.FloatField(),
                )
            ),
        )
        .filter(
            votes_above_threshold__gt=0,
        )
)
```